# Hi, Could someone help me in resolving below mentioned error issue. I am frequently facing the issue and not able to launch the remote webdriver

Tags: json, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

```
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: 
E. Last 1 characters read: EBuild info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 
'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'System info: host: 'EX-CON-
2255C', ip: '10.185.18.14', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', 
os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.16.1'Driver info: 
driver.version: RemoteWebDriver    at 
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonInput.peek(JsonInput.java:122)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.lambda$null$6(JsonTypeCoercer.
java:140)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonTypeCoercer.coerce(JsonTypeCoercer.java:12
6)    at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:69)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:55)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.toType(Json.java:50)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResp
onseCodec.java:87)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResp
onseCodec.java:49)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecu
tor.java:158)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java
:552)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java
:609)    at 
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDri
ver.java:295)    at 
qxhresponsive.PinkStrawberry.utilities.ExtentReporter.getScreenShot(Ext
entReporter.java:195)    at 
qxhresponsive.PinkStrawberry.utilities.ExtentReporter.reportStep(Extent
Reporter.java:138)    at 
qxhresponsive.PinkStrawberry.pages.ConvivaPage.navigateToConviva(Conviv
aPage.java:61)    at 
qxhresponsive.PinkStrawberry.tests.ConvivaTest.ZSMED_T9004_MP_8807_US_W
eb_New_Ventures_Program_Guide_Automation_of_GA_and_Conviva_Live_channes
_from_first_column(ConvivaTest.java:100)    at 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native 
Method)    at 
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMe
thodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at
```

Tried added wait time, Since i am using both android web driver and Web driver for a particular scenario

Answer (score 0):

Please share capabilities you are passing. Error message you are getting `Unable to determine type from: E. Last 1 characters read:`  indicates you are sharing capabilities either in incorrect JSON format or incorrect value

You can utilize sauce labs platform configurator to configure capabilities "https://saucelabs.com/products/platform-configurator"